# Errors "noscript", W3C XHTML

Tags: xhtml, w3c-validation, head, noscript

I am trying to validate my document as XHTML 1.0 Transitional (W3C).

I have the following error:
"document type does not allow element "noscript" here; assuming missing "object" start-tag"
which corresponds to this code:

```
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt=""
src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/1096/?
value=1.00&amp;label=Y-skCMY_QM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
</head>
```

But I get this validation failing. What is the problem? Please help me to solve this.

Comment: The XHTML definition doesn't include `noscript`. Your choices are to ignore the W3C error, use another doctype or use another way to detect javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your solutions could be to place it in the `body` instead of the `head` of your document as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt=""
src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/1096/?
value=1.00&amp;label=Y-skCMY_QM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

This results in:

`This document was successfully checked as XHTML 1.0 Transitional!`

Additionally, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/642641/2510628), it seams that it doesn’t really make difference (I'm talking about `head` vs `body` here):

> Have done the move with the Google Ad section outside of HEAD and just
>   in the BODY part itself. Really doesn't make a difference since when
>   it was moved, it was just right after the parameters used for the ads
>   to display.

**Solution #2**
In case You will need to get rid of the `<noscript>` at all, You can try to make the following:

```
<div id='noscript' style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt=""
src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/1096/?
value=1.00&amp;label=Y-skCMY_QM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
<script>document.getElementById('noscript').style.display='none'</script>
```

This makes things work absolutely the same as in the first solution. If JavaScript is disabled, `<script>...</script>` won't be executed, thus `<div>...</div>` would be shown.